# Can't set http-only and secure cookies in Apache

Tags: amazon-web-services, vps, apache2, amazon-elb

My website is on Apache which is hosted in AWS VPS.

I tried setting http-only flag and secure flag by editing security.conf file but upon checking the headers via https://hackertarget.com/http-header-check/ 
I see that there is no change and cookies are still without these flags.

I followed these steps:

Ensure you have mod_headers.so enabled in Apache HTTP server

Add following entry in */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf*

**Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure**

Restart Apache HTTP server to test

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the last part in "" like i did here:

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"
```

After that try a apache syntax check with:

```
apachectl -t
```

Very good test for header security is the one from mozilla:

> https://observatory.mozilla.org/

Answer (score -1):

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"
```

There can be two reasons for set-cookie flag not working:

1. Header control with CGI and not with Apache.
2. AWS ELB truncating the cookies (in case your website is behind a load balancer).

If it is the first case, this answer will work as it worked for me.

Comment: This is a terrible self-answer. a) use correct formatting tools. b) point to what you fixed. c) This seems to have been answered by another user. Fair approach would be to upvote and accept his answer.

Comment: I would've gladly accepted his answer if it had worked for me. I posted my answer so that if someone faces the same problem in future, they can know what worked for me. Sorry for the wrong formatting.